# How to insert data into a SQLite Database only if the value does not exist?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to insert vales into a date base only if the database is empty. If is empty i want to insert all the `db.addQuestion`. If the questions are already there, i don't want to insert anything.
This is the code from the MainActivity where i insert the questions into the database:

```
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);

    // Inserting Questions
    db.addQuestion(new Question("1. Question 1", 1));
    db.addQuestion(new Question("2. Question 2", 2));
    db.addQuestion(new Question("3. Question 3", 3));
    db.addQuestion(new Question("4. Question 4", 4));
    db.addQuestion(new Question("5. Question 5", 5));

    // Reading all Questions
    List<Question> questions = db.getAllQuestions();
```

This is the code from the DBHandler where i create table, add a new question and get all questions.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUESTIONS + "("
            + KEY_QUESTION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_ORDER_NO + " INTEGER " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
}

// Adding New Question
void addQuestion(Question question) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
    values.put(KEY_ORDER_NO, question.getorderNo());

    db.insert(TABLE_QUESTIONS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

// Getting All Questions
public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUESTIONS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // Looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Question question = new Question();
            question.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            question.setQuestion(cursor.getString(1));
            question.setorderNo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            // Adding Questions to List
            questionList.add(question);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return questionList;
}
```

And what if i have 2 or more tables? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a value unique then check database value is already exists or not during insert . 
like this :

checking method :

```
public boolean dataExists(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_QUESION_ID + "=" + id;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
```

and insert

```
void addQuestion(Question question) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
    values.put(KEY_ORDER_NO, question.getorderNo());
  if (dataExists(question.getQuestionId())) {
            db.update(TABLE_QUESTION, values, KEY_QUESTION_ID + "=" + question.getQuestionId(), null);
        } else {
            db.insert(TABLE_QUESTOIN, null, values);
            db.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: This is what i'm trying to do. Thank you. But please explain to me, what is that `rate` from `rate.getQuestionId()`. I get an error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'rate'`

Comment: oh sorry it was for my case , it's a object of model class . 
for your case it should be 'question' for Question class  dude .

Comment: And now seems that the `getQuestionId()` si not recognized. Can you please edit the answer with the correct lines?

Comment: it's a example dude you please make getter and setter for every element of Question class . and fix what is your unique field then do like this. 
I just trying to give example that's why i write this .